# python ImportError: cannot import name D

Tags: python-2.7, import

Well, seems to be a popular question. I browsed through existing answers and tried applying the suitable solutions but did not work. So....

Scenario: TriangulationPkg is installed and has added files counter.py and definition.py under a directory /home/share/xy/lib/.

```
$ls /home/share/xy/lib
counter.py definition.py
```

This works fine when I execute the corresponding script. Following are the entries in corresponding files.

```
triangulation.py:
sys.path.append('/home/share/xy/lib')
from counter import a, b, c
```

and

```
counter.py
from definition import D
```

I am trying to replicate the things in myscript.py as

```
myscript.py:
sys.path.append('/home/share/xy/lib')
from counter import a, b, c
```

But when I try to execute the script is gives error as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/share/xy/lib/counter.py", line 17, in <module>
   from definition import D
ImportError: cannot import name D
```

1. I tried executing raw triangulation.py script lying in a directory and not from package executable it works..! But not for myscript.py in the similar way.
2. Tried "from counter import a, b, c" from python prompt, gives same error even after sys.path.append

Any help is highly appreciated...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED : I had a file named definition.py in my local directory and that was conflicting with the import with the same name. The local fine did not have D to import hence the error.